# how to iterate json String

Tags: java, json

I have an array of JSON strings like:

```
[{
"id":"BirthDate",
"field":"BirthDate",
"type":"date",
"input":"text",
"operator":"equal",
"value":"2016/04/07"
}]
```

I want to be able to iterate this array and want to get its id, field, value in Java

Using the below code I got an exception 
"json object must begin with {"

```
String rules=helper.getRules();
    System.out.println("====Rulses=====:"+rules);
      try {
           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(rules);
           System.out.println("====obj===="+obj);
          // boolean error = obj.getBoolean("error");
           String id = obj.getString("id");
           System.out.println("===id is===: "+id);
      } catch (JSONException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: What you have is a JSON array, containing a single object.

Comment: i got this string from ajax [{"id":"BirthDate","field":"BirthDate","type":"date","input":"text","operator":"equal","value":"2016/04/07"}] i just want to iterate this

Comment: Yes. And it's a JSON *array*, not an object. Much like the error message is telling you. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: i unable to iterate this jsonArray

Comment: i got this array in the form of String

Comment: Yes, JSON is a *string* format. You need to parse it *as an array*. I don't know which JSON library you're using, but `new JSONObject(rules)` sure looks like you're trying to parse it as an *object*, and as the error message says, objects begin with `{`. Try `new JSONArray(rules)`, or whatever the library offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead create a `JSONArray` from the String and then iterate over the array. Modify your code as

```
String rules=helper.getRules();
System.out.println("====Rulses=====:"+rules);
try {
    // create the json array from String rules
    JSONArray jsonRules = new JSONArray(rules);
    // iterate over the rules 
    for (int i=0; i<jsonRules.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonRules.get(i);
        System.out.println("====obj===="+obj);

        String id = obj.getString("id");
        System.out.println("===id is===: "+id);
    }
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this parsing your `rules`into a `JSONArray`:

```
String rules = "[{\"id\":\"BirthDate\",\"field\":\"BirthDate\",\"type\":\"date\",\"input\":\"text\",\"operator\":\"equal\",\"value\":\"2016/04/07\"}]";

try {
    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(rules); // parse the array
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++){ // iterate over the array
        JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = o.getString("id");
        System.out.println("===id is===: " + id);
    }
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the JSON you gave as example you just have one element in your array.